# unable to grab the children div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab a `div` inside a `divContainer`.
On a menu mouse over I am grabbing the value of custom data attribute and the name of div to grab.
Now the code is:

```
containerNameToGrab = $(this).attr('data-containerName');
```

It returns `menu1Container`.
Now i added a `#` using this `containerNameToGrab = '#' + containerNameToGrab;`.
And finally I am trying to find the `div` using this:

```
currentContainerDiv = $('.mainMenuSlidingContainer').find(containerNameToGrab);
```

Now, when i checked the value of `currentContainerDiv` **it returned `Object object`**.
Please tell me where I am doing it wrong. 
Thanks.

**OK THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED NOW I USED # directly in data-customattribute and then grabbed the lement. thanks.**

Comment: If that's an ID, why not just do `$(containerNameToGrab )`

Comment: use `currentContainerDiv=$('.mainMenuSlidingContainer').find('#'+containerNameToGrab );`

Comment: the code looks fine to me. run some code on `currentContainerDiv` to confirm its the correct element. provide a fiddle and we can help you better

Comment: @TamilSelvan  using your cvode still displays Object Object.

Comment: @tymeJV it still returns an object.

Comment: That's a jQuery object it returns... what do you expect?